# Using PHP to clean up a url

Tags: php

I have the following line of PHP:

`echo "<li>".str_replace("http://", "", rtrim($row['website'],"/"))."</li>";`

That removes the http:// and the trailing slash from a url. However I also want it to remove https:// but don't want to wrap it in another str_replace.

Is their a better and more efficient way of doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try:

```
str_replace(array("http://","https://"), "", rtrim($row['website'],"/")
```